# Access dockerfiles for the GCP deep-learning-platform images

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deep-learning, google-dl-platform

I'm using images derived from the [deep-learning containers](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/deep-learning-containers/docs/) to run several tasks in the AI Platform Notebooks product.
In order to make some changes to my derived images, it would be really helpful to know how the parent images are built but I can't find a repository for the code that actually builds the images (ie. the Dockerfiles) anywhere. Does anyone know where these can be found?

I can obviously pull up the [container registry](https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/deeplearning-platform-release/GLOBAL/tf2-gpu.2-0?gcrImageListsize=30), but that doesn't help me to see how the images are built...

Comment: I dont think they are open source.

Comment: You can pull a container image and show the "history" for the container. This shows you how it is built and what the original starting image. This does not mean that you access the original image. You can add to and remove parts of the image. You can also export an image to a `tar` archive file, modify and then reimport.

Comment: Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75291419/2023941